# Adding/Editing a path on an image

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have an image which I have to annotate with several contours. I use the following code to display a contour along with its handles:

```
const path = new paper.Path({
    segments: contours,
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeWidth: 10
  });
```

The contour is an array of Points. This part works perfectly.

Now, I want to be able to edit the above contour. The idea is that I should be able to remove a segment if I (for example) double click on it.

I see the API method: http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#removesegment-index. If I had the index of the segment that I wanted to remove, I could do it. How do I get the index of the segment that I have clicked on?

Secondly, I also want the possibility of changing the shape of the contour. For this I want to be able to move the handles (which I believe correspond to the x-y coordinates that I use to draw the path). How do I do that?

Thirdly, I want to be able to draw a contour. The UX should work in the following manner:

- When I click on a picture, it adds a point.
- When I click again, it adds a second point and draws a segment between the first and the second point.
- It keeps doing this, until I click the first Point, at which point it closes the path.

The approach that I have in mind is as follows:

- Add an onMouseDown event handler to the view.
- Add a point on click if I am in the "add new contour" mode.
- Draw a segment when I have two points connected.
- If I have 3 or more points, and I click again on the first point, I close the path.

I have two queries regarding this:

- What is the best way to check that I have clicked in the general vicinity of the first point?
- How do I ensure that my shape is not crossing over itself?

An additional style question - how do I style the appearance of the handles?

Thanks for your help,
Rahul

Comment: This example will help you: http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/

Comment: Thanks @arthur.sw, that's exactly what I was looking for.